# Application Insights TrackException ExceptionTelemetry when you do not have an exception object

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights, http-error

If you have a serialized exception, such as you may with a HTTP Error response, but no exception object, does anyone have an example of constructing a new ExceptionTelemetry() that Application Insights will log?

Comment: Create an exception yourself, add as much info as possible and track that. Obviously you will miss the Stack Trace as you cannot set that but you could add more details in the custom properties. What data do you have?

Comment: I have an entire exception serialized (in a JSON body) and I'd like to call public void TrackException(ExceptionTelemetry telemetry).

Comment: Have you tried to deserialize it back to an exception and call `TrackException`?

Comment: This question isn't about calling .TrackException when you have an exception object, it is about when you do not.  MS has an option for this, and there are no examples I have been able to find.

Comment: Just out of curiosity and for me to learn: what makes you think MS has an option for this? I am not aware of anything to do this. I might just misunderstand the question. Are we talking about manually tracking an error / exception?

Comment: We are talking about .TrackException( new ExceptionTelemetry(...) );

Answer (score 2):

Given a serialized exception in JSON exceptionBody, I did get Application Insights to add the details with the code below.  However, I don't really know what should be put in id or outerId, or how to easily fill in the List of StackFrame, or if passing the stack as a string means you don't pass the List of 
 StackFrame

```
    var responseAsJObject = JObject.Parse(exceptionBody);
    var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var pair in responseAsJObject)
    {
        properties.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value.ToString());
    }

    var measurements = new Dictionary<string, double>();

    var hasFullStack = properties.TryGetValue("StackTrace", out var stack);

     var edi = new ExceptionDetailsInfo
    (
        10000,
        10000,
        properties["ExceptionType"],
        $"{properties["Message"]} {url}",
        hasFullStack,
        stack ?? string.Empty,
        new List<StackFrame>()
    );

    var exceptionTelemetry = new ExceptionTelemetry
    (
        new List<ExceptionDetailsInfo>{edi},
        SeverityLevel.Error,
        $"HTTP Error {statusCode}",
        properties,
        measurements
    );

    telemetryClient.TrackException(exceptionTelemetry);
```